# Computer not booting past motherboard manufacturer logo

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bootloader

My PC doesn't go past the motherboard manufacturer logo.
I tried to reset the BIOS.
I have two RAM slots and 1GB RAM. I tried reinserting the RAM in other slots.

[image]

I think the red light shows that the hard drive is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Does it get stuck up therE?

Comment: Yes,it doesnt go beyond it.!!

Comment: How old is your PC?

Comment: May be 5 years..!!

Comment: If the red light is on solid, I'd check all my connections inside the box (reseat the RAM, the power supply, the hard drive connections, etc.). Most likely though, at this age, something on the power supply or motherboard is broken. Difficult to test on such an old machine, too.

Comment: i have double checked all the connections..tried re-connecting them...i have replaced power supply few months back,as it got damaged.And red light is solid.

Comment: Can you edit the bios to not show the manufacturer logo? If so, it will probably show detailed output, which should make it a lot easier to track down the source of the problem.

Comment: I cant get to the bios, only after passing through the manufacturer logo, i can go to bios

Answer (score -1):

Try cleaning up the insides of the CPU (specifically the RAM, processor etc) with a vacuum cleaner. This worked for a friend of mine who had the same problem.

Comment: Yes,i tried doing it..but did'nt use a vacuum cleaner

Comment: A vacuum cleaner is an exceptionally bad idea. It's a static nightmare. You should use a gas duster (compressed air in a can), available from most computer and electronics stores. Either way, I think the computer is probably dead. My vote is motherboard issue.

Comment: Thanks Randolph...i hope its not dead , i use it as a secondary pc ,when i have to download Gigs of data..

Comment: So I get a downvote for saying vacuum cleaner?